# WinForm Button stops working after 1-2 uses

Tags: c#, .net

I have a program that quizzes the user by naming a Country (from a list) and asks the user to input it's Capital. If they get it correct, a counter for correct answers is shown with +1 added to it. If it is wrong, the same thing goes but for the incorrect counter. I finished the code for it, but whenever I use the Check Answer button, it doesn't verify the input from the TextBox anymore, and none of the counters (correct or incorrect) change at all. If the first one is right and the second is wrong, it counts both 1 for correct and 1 for incorrect. After that the code under the Check Answer button doesn't execute anymore. If I got 2 right or 2 wrong it only counts the first 1 and stops working after.

```
{
//  Declare structure
struct Country
{
    //  Declare strings
    public string countryName;
    public string capital;
}
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    //  Create List for CourseInfo
    private List<Country> countryList = new List<Country>();

    Country currentCountry;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void ReadFile()
    {
        try
        {
            //  Call StreamReader to use imported file
            StreamReader inputFile;
            string line;

            Country entry = new Country();

            //  Delimiter to separate values in text file
            char[] delim = { ',' };

            //  Open text file
            inputFile = File.OpenText("countries.txt");

            while (!inputFile.EndOfStream)
            {
                line = inputFile.ReadLine();

                //  Tokenize the strings separated by the delimiter ','
                string[] tokens = line.Split(delim);

                entry.countryName = tokens[0];   //  Tokenized entry for COUNTRY
                entry.capital = tokens[1];       //  Tokenized entry for CAPITAL

                countryList.Add(entry);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //  Shows error message
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }


    private void DisplayCountry()
    {
        //  Create random variable
        Random rand = new Random();

        //  Country us randomly chosen from the list
        int countryPosition = rand.Next(countryList.Count);

        //  Selected country
        currentCountry = countryList[countryPosition];

        //  Show selected country in Label
        countryAnswerLabel.Text = currentCountry.countryName;
    }

    private void ExitButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //  Closes the form
        this.Close();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //  Call method to load StreamReader with the file
        ReadFile();
    }

    private void QuizButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //  Call method to show random country
        DisplayCountry();
    }

    private void CheckAnswerButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //  Declare integer variables for the counters and set to 0
        int correctCounter = 0;
        int incorrectCounter = 0;

        //  If the input is correct, +1 for the correct counter
        if (currentCountry.capital == capitalAnswerTextBox.Text)
        {
            correctCounter++;
            correctLabel.Text = correctCounter.ToString();
        }
        //  If the input is incorrect, +1 for the incorrect counter
        else
        {
            incorrectCounter++;
            incorrectLabel.Text = incorrectCounter.ToString();
        }
    }

    private void NextQuestionButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //  Clears input TextBox
        capitalAnswerTextBox.Text = string.Empty;
        DisplayCountry();

    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Both your `int` variables are defined locally, therefore, their values start at zero each time you click the button no matter how many times you do `++`. See: [Scope and Visibility](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-language/scope-and-visibility).

Comment: Yeah you're right... I see now. Thanks for the quick help

Comment: So the button works, it just there is a bug in your code. Maybe the title is misleading then. Maybe something more like "Result not what expected after button press" would make this post a little clearer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Notice that whenever `CheckAnswerButton_Click` is executed, the variables `correctCounter` and `incorrectCounter` are initialised to 0. So every time you press the button, you start counting the answers from 0 again. So you will always be setting one of label's `Text` to `"1"`. In case that label already shows `"1"`, it would seem like it's "not doing anything".

Therefore, you should move the declarations of `correctCount` and `incorrectCounter` to outside the `CheckAnswerButton_Click` method:

```
//  Declare integer variables for the counters and set to 0
int correctCounter = 0;
int incorrectCounter = 0;
private void CheckAnswerButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    //  If the input is correct, +1 for the correct counter
    if (currentCountry.capital == capitalAnswerTextBox.Text)
    {
        correctCounter++;
        correctLabel.Text = correctCounter.ToString();
    }
    //  If the input is incorrect, +1 for the incorrect counter
    else
    {
        incorrectCounter++;
        incorrectLabel.Text = incorrectCounter.ToString();
    }
}
```

This way, they will retain their value after `CheckAnswerButton_Click` has returned.